# Unpack slices on assignment?

Tags: go

Is there an elegant way in Go to do multiple assignments from arrays like in Python? Here is a Python example of what I'm trying to do (split a string and then assign the resulting array into two variables).

```
python:
>>> a, b = "foo;bar".split(";")
```

My current solution is:

```
x := strings.Split("foo;bar", ";")
a, b := x[0], x[1]
```

I'm can see this getting messy in some constructs. The practical example I'm currently facing is a bookmark file parsing and assigning to a map:

```
bookmark := make(map[string]string)
x := strings.Split("foo\thttps://bar", "\t")
name, link := x[0], x[1]
bookmark[name] = link
```

Now I have a useless variable `x` sitting around. I'd like to do something like:

```
bookmark := make(map[string]string)
name, line := strings.Split("foo\thttps://bar", "\t")
bookmark[name] = link
```

but that's invalid.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

As Sergio Tulentsev mentioned, general packing/unpacking as is done in Python is not supported. I think the way to go there is to define your own small ad-hoc function using multiple return values:

```
func splitLink(s, sep string) (string, string) {
    x := strings.Split(s, sep)
    return x[0], x[1]
}
```

And you can then write:

```
name, link := splitLink("foo\thttps://bar", "\t")
```

But this will obviously work only when at least two substrings are being split, and silently ignore if more than two were. If this is something you use a lot, it might make your code more readable though.

**--EDIT--**

Another way to unpack an array is via variadic pointer arguments:

```
func unpack(s []string, vars... *string) {
    for i, str := range s {
        *vars[i] = str
    }
}
```

Which let you write:

```
var name, link string
unpack(strings.Split("foo\thttps://bar", "\t"), &name, &link)
bookmarks[name] = link
```

This will work for any array size, but it is arguably less readable, and you have to declare your variables explicitly.

Answer (score 19):

You could also use anonymous functions:

```
a, b := func() (string, string) {
    x := strings.Split("foo;bar", ";")
    return x[0], x[1]
}()
```

Note: don't forget the `()` on the end of the closing bracket `}` otherwise you will get the error:

`assignment mismatch: 2 variable but 1 values`

This is because without the `()` a function (1 value) is returned not the expected strings (2 values).

Comment: Is this common to do in golang? If I do it only once, should I prefer using it instead of creating an ad-hoc function?

Comment: if it's something simple like this that you'll use one-off in your codebase it's fine. Depends on the size and style of your project though, don't want to just start dropping these if you already have a package dedicated to ad-hoc functions

Comment: Would be nice to have: `x, y, z := ...array`

Answer (score 10):

If your function is meant to split a string only by the first occurrence of the separator, you can always make your own function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func Split(s, sep string) (string, string) {
    // Empty string should just return empty
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return s, s
    }   

    slice := strings.SplitN(s, sep, 2)

    // Incase no separator was present
    if len(slice) == 1 {
        return slice[0], ""
    }

    return slice[0], slice[1]
}

func main() {
    a, b := Split("foo;bar;foo", ";")
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

Output:

> foo bar;foo

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Aa-dy1bFHR)

Comment: "you can always make your own function" - go community about every possible missing feature of the go.