# What's the go equivalent to PHP's list()?

Tags: arrays, regex, go

In PHP we have the `list()` which enable us to assign values to a list of variables in one operation. Eg:

```php
list($a, $b) = ['valueA', 'valueB'];
echo $a; # valueA
echo $b; # valueB
```

Is it possible do the same thing in Go? Functions like [`Regexp.FindStringSubmatch()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch) returns an array, so would be nice map this values directly into other variables.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832189/unpack-golang-slices-on-assignment for use of unpacking, no list constructor required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that in go, but there is a way to achieve that by taking advantage the pointer value of it's variable.

Create a function, pass pointer of all receiver variables as slices, then re-assign the value.

```
func main() {
    var arr = []string{"value 1", "value 2", "value 3"}
    var a, b, c string

    vcopy(arr, &a, &b, &c)

    fmt.Println(a) // value 1
    fmt.Println(b) // value 2
    fmt.Println(c) // value 3
}

func vcopy(arr []string, dest ...*string) {
    for i := range dest {
        if len(arr) > i {
            *dest[i] = arr[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Example http://play.golang.org/p/gJzWp1WglJ

By using this technique, passing any variables are not a problem.

Comment: This is just bad practice, why would anyone use that rather than: `a, b, c := s[0], s[1], s[2]`? also that's a slice not an array.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in but you can write your own function to do something similar:

```
func unlist(x []string) (string, string) {
    return x[0], x[1]
}

a, b := unlist(values);
```

However, this does mean that there is no way to generalize this which means that you have to write a function for destructuring* every different number and type of argument you need it for.

*note: the general name for this operation is a "destructuring assignment".

Comment: this isn't even valid go..

Comment: @OneOfOne: I'm very sorry but someone keeps editing the answer to be invalid. He obviously doesn't understand how go's multiple return values work.

Comment: @Noval Agung Prayogo: Please don't change working code into invalid code. Please learn about how go's return work

Comment: @OneOfOne: Thank you

Comment: This is your previous code http://play.golang.org/p/pPYHpUBq6B and it's definitely invalid. Or am I the only one who doesn't understand go multiple return?

Comment: you keep deleting the return type `(string, string)`, and in the end you approve @OneOfOne answer which is exaclty did the same thing like what I did, cmon bruh, really

Comment: check out this! still one of the funniest thing I ever saw on SO :D https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36855354/revisions

slebetman rejects my edit two times, but approving @OneOfOne answer which does the very same thing like what I did lmao